# Trying to save a file to a folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to save a file from my website to a folder but when I click on the button that was created by me it will download the file I want it to download into the folder I wand and not the downloads folder => hope this makes sense :)

```
class Export extends CI_Controller{

    public function excel(){

        $this->load->model('AfterClassFeedback_model');

        // get the information from the table to put on the page
        $feedback = new AfterClassFeedback_model;
        $feedback->table = 'afterclassfeedback';
        $feedback->primary_key = 'id';
        $data['list'] = $feedback->read();

       require(APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
       require(APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');

       $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        // you can set some properties here 
       //$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");

       $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

       // setting the values in the active sheet
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'ID');
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Date Added');
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Question 1');
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'Question 2');
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'Question 3');
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'Question 4');
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', 'Question 5');

       $row = 2;
    //    echo "<pre>";
    //     print_r($data['list']);
    //    echo "</pre>";

       foreach($data['list'] as $key => $value){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row,$value->id);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row,$value->date_added);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row,$value->question1);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$row,$value->question2);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$row,$value->question3);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$row,$value->question4);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$row,$value->question5);

        $row++;
       }

       $path =  base_url();
       $fullPath = 'uploads';
       $filename = "FEED_BACK_REPORT".date("ymd")."_TIME_".date("H:i:s").'.xlsx';
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetTitle("After_Class_Feedback_Report");
       $myLocation = $path.$fullPath;
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/save");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

       $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

       $writer->save('php://output', 'w');

       exit;
    }
```

Comment: That's a browser setting. You can't decide on the server side where you file will be downloaded when you click the download button.

Comment: Just THINK of the consequences if you were allowed to do that. I could download and place files anywhere on your system. **A hackers paradise**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is ___You cant do that___ for good reasons

Comment: ha ha ha so it cant be done because I create a folder when the user registers then I want them to be able to save pdf files or excel files to that folder ??????

Comment: Did we get the wrong end of the stick? Looks like you are trying to send the file to the users PC. Is that not what you are trying to do??

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to do

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, you need to set the download folder in your browser

Comment: please use comment section

Comment: I see you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead